Is there a smart Typescript way to handle complex union type problems with the Notion SDK?
I'm writing a function in Typescript for cloning a specified block/page in Notion using their API. Since there isn't a provided endpoint for duplicating pages programmatically, I've decided to attempt doing so myself (I'm sure solutions already exist for this and will be better than what I write, but I don't care).
I'm able to recursively iterate over all of the nested children for the specified page, but am now running into some issues when it comes to the actual generation of the duplicated blocks. Specifically, the BlockObjectResponse type provided by Notion, which is defined as a union of some 30-odd other response types.
. These union'd types all seem to possess certain common properties such as type, id, parent (which is itself another convoluted union type), etc., which I need for reconstructing the relationships when making the API requests to create my copy (I throw away properties that don't matter, such as edit times, users, etc.). However, the numerous fields that differ between these make it difficult to reuse my code, and I've resorted to an ugly switch statement-based parsing that I feel must surely have better alternatives.


I've resorted to workarounds like grabbing the type values for all the child objects as strings and iterating over them, with wonky JSON serializing-and-unserializing to avoid the Typescript complaints. Is there an idiomatic way to better narrow these types and avoid some/all of these workarounds?

To those of you who are struggling with the same concerns as I am, I present the following code. I too had many concerns due to the complex type structure, but I finally resolved them. It works flawlessly without any errors.
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { BlockObjectResponse, RichTextItemResponse } from '@notionhq/client/build/src/api-endpoints';
import { notion } from '@/notion';

type Block<T extends string> = Extract<BlockObjectResponse, { type: T }> & {
  [K in T]: {
    rich_text: RichTextItemResponse[];
    color: string;
  };
};

const strict = <T>(arg: any) => arg as unknown as T;

const getBlock = (block: BlockObjectResponse) => {
  if (block.type === 'divider') return { rich_text: [], color: 'default' };
  return strict<Block<typeof block.type>>(block)[block.type];
};

/* ======================= skipping the middle ======================= */

export async function GET(_: NextRequest, { params }: NextContext) {

  const { results } = await notion.blocks.children.list({
    block_id,
  });

  const blocks = results.slice(1) as BlockObjectResponse[];

  /* ============== skipping the middle ============== */

  return NextResponse.json(
    blocks.map(block => {
      const { id, type, has_children } = block;
      const { rich_text, color } = getBlock(block);
      return {
        id,
        type,
        content: merge(rich_text),
        color,
        has_children,
      };
    })
  );
}

